# Set wallpaper in Android

Tags: android, android-image

I have image 640*480 in sd card and i want to set it as home screen wallpaper. How Can I do this with small quality loss? With my code Wallpaper has a not good clarity. That's my code:

```
private void setWallpaper(String filePath) throws IOException{
    if(filePath!=null){
    // set options for decoding
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    options.inDither = false;   
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    //get bitmap from filepath
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    //get sizes of bitmap
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();
    //get sizes of screen and scale level
    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int newWidth = display.getWidth()*2;
    int newHeight = display.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    //set matrix of the scaling
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    //get new bitmap for wallpaper
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,
            width, height, matrix, true);
    //set bitmap as wallpaper
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    wallpaperManager.clear();
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(resizedBitmap);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you scale upwards you're going to suffer quality loss. What size screen are you trying to display this image one? Keep in mind the Android wallpaper dimensions are the height of the screen by 2 times the width of the screen (e.g. 800x480 screen needs a 800x960 image).

My recommendation would be to have a larger image and scale downwards. The quality loss from downsampling is far less noticeable than from upscaling. You could, if space is not an issue, include multiple sizes of the image for differing screen resolutions.

Comment: com.coolaris.media upscaling image with good quality and clarity when I set this image as wallpaper. But I don't know how to use this package in my program.